# Gitlab: Godot export failing to Linux, Mac OSX, and Windows, on the 'test' step

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-image, godot

I have copied the basic template for making a Gitlab CI/CD for my Godot project. After running triggering, only the HTML5 export is built successfull, and not the Linux, Mac OSX, or Windows, even though I'm using the default export templates for all.

It all fails on the `test -e .....` step, that is, after everything is built properly.
Only the `Web` build passes this step, none others, despite the same recipe being followed. Interestingly, while playing this build using an offline webserver, I can not go past the first screen too, which is not the case when I play it in Godot Run project.

My .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: barichello/godot-ci:3.3

variables:
  EXPORT_NAME: Game


stages:
  - export

before_script:
  - mkdir -v -p build/linux
  - mkdir -v -p build/windows
  - mkdir -v -p build/mac
  - mkdir -v -p build/web

linux:
  stage: export
  script:
    - cd TestProjectGodot
    - godot -v --export "Linux/X11" ../build/linux/$EXPORT_NAME.x86_64
    - test -e ../build/linux/$EXPORT_NAME.x86_64
  artifacts:
    name: $EXPORT_NAME-$CI_JOB_NAME
    paths:
      - build/linux
  only:
      - release

windows:
  stage: export
  script:
    - cd TestProjectGodot
    - godot -v --export "Windows Desktop" ../build/windows/$EXPORT_NAME.exe
    - test -e ../build/windows/$EXPORT_NAME.exe
  artifacts:
    name: $EXPORT_NAME-$CI_JOB_NAME
    paths:
      - build/windows
  only:
      - release

mac:
  stage: export
  script:
    - cd TestProjectGodot
    - godot -v --export "Mac OSX" ../build/mac/$EXPORT_NAME.zip
    - test -e ../build/mac/$EXPORT_NAME.zip
  artifacts:
    name: $EXPORT_NAME-$CI_JOB_NAME
    paths:
      - build/mac
  only:
      - release

web:
  stage: export
  script:
    - cd TestProjectGodot
    - godot -v --path TestProjectGodot --export "HTML5" ../build/web/index.html
    - test -e ../build/web/index.html
  artifacts:
    name: $EXPORT_NAME-$CI_JOB_NAME
    paths:
      - build/web
  only:
      - release
```

My root from the branch looks like this:-
[image: screenshot of root in 'release' branch]

The error that I receive (in all the 3 versions), and the parent step: (this one is from the `Windows` target,, for example)

```
savepack: end
reimport: end
EditorSettings: Save OK!

$ test -e ../build/windows/$EXPORT_NAME.exe
/usr/bin/bash: line 131: test: too many arguments
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any ideas as to what is going on, that makes it fail? In the future, I will try to use the offline `godot export ...` utitlity to see if the errors persist.
If not, then something may be wrong with Docker image itself at this point. If there is, Godot engine might have +1 bug.